# Maximum recursion depth exceeded in my comparison

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, insertion-sort

I am currently reading the Introduction to Algorithms (CLRS). While trying to solve exercise 2.3-4 which is to write insertion sort of A by recursively sorting A[:n-1]. I have written a code for that which i will show below where I generated a list of random numbers and tried to sort it, and it works for up to a certain number of items in the list but when i bumped it up to a thousand I get an error saying maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison, from checking online I noticed there is a way to increase recursion depth to a certain value, but I am not sure if that is good practice or I should improve my code in some way. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

```
import random
numlist = []
for i in range(1000):
    numlist.append(i)
random.shuffle(numlist)

def rec_ins_sort(L):
    if(len(L) == 1):
        return L
    else:
        step = rec_ins_sort(L[:len(L)-1])
        return insert(L[len(L)-1], step)

def insert(a, inp_list):
    inp_list.append(a)
    i = len(inp_list) - 2
    while(i > 0 and inp_list[i] > a):
        inp_list[i+1] = inp_list[i]
        i -= 1
    inp_list[i+1] = a
    return inp_list
```

Comment: Recurion in the size of a list is usually never a good idea. Since the call stack scales with the number of items.

Comment: Algorithms that recurse to a depth proportional to the size of the input aren't a good fit for Python. That's something you'd do in functional languages like Scheme, which are designed to allow much deeper call stacks.

Comment: isnt merge sort a recursive sorting method using divide and conquer? that seems to work. where should it be avoided

Comment: @ariamis07: that's because it recurses with *O(log n)*, with *n* the *size* of the input.

Comment: No. Merge sort is a divide and conquer - logarithmic complexity recursion depth.

Comment: Yeah I understand now. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I am not sure if that is good practice or I should improve my code in some way.

Algorithms that recurse **linear** (or superlinear) **in the *size* of the input** are usually not a good idea, except if the programming language supports *tail call optimization (TCO)* (Python does not) and the program is *tail recursive*. In which case the call stack simply does not grow because the last call frame is overwritten.

*MergeSort* for instance is an algorithm that recurses in *O(log n)* with *n* the size of the input. As a result the call stack does not grow much: if the list has 1'073'741'824 elements, the call stack will grow ~30 levels deep.

For **insertion sort**. I do not really see an elegant way to let it recurse in *O(log n)*, so you better do not use recursion at all: you can simply use iteration here:

```
def rec_ins_sort(L):
    iflen(L) < 1:
        return L
    else:
        R = []
        for l in L:
            R = insert(l,R)
        return R

def insert(a, inp_list):
    inp_list.append(a)
    i = len(inp_list) - 2
    while(i > 0 and inp_list[i] > a):
        inp_list[i+1] = inp_list[i]
        i -= 1
    inp_list[i+1] = a
    return inp_list
```

That being said constructing new lists, etc. is not very efficient either making this algorithm slower than strictly necessary.

So to summarize: you better do not construct algorithms in Python that recurse (super)linear in the size of the input. In that case you better aim to convert it to an iterative approach.

Comment: I understand now. The only reason I tried recursion for insertion sort was because the question was to find the running time for recursive insertion sort. But yeah I will keep it in mind. Thanks a lot for the answer